# Magento Connect Manager: Access is locked. Please try again in a few minutes

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

does anyone encounter similar issue with this?

"Access is locked. Please try again in a few minutes."

[image: Access is locked. Please try again in a few minutes.]

I did clear,flush the cache, reindex but still not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally! What worked for me was setting

```
brute-force-bad-attempts-count = 0
```

in  **var/brute-force.ini**

Source:
https://dx3webs.com/blog/access-is-locked

Comment: This worked for me. It has security implications though and you should read and consider the advice given in the link about moving the downloader folder.

Comment: This was necessary because that security mechanism (anti brute force) was simply broken on the Magento side.  Somehow, a single browser session caused it to increment inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<magento-root>/downloader` directory recursively 777 permissions, after your extension installation set it back to the original permission settings.

Comment: It's kinda weird but it just disappears after a couple of minutes then I tried it back it's gone.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Cause i am facing the same issue. How did you solve it?